# Amazon S3 on-prem Data Lake

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

Can install Amazon S3 on-prem? If yes, then does anyone have a download link to it please? I have tried using Amazon S3 Cloud Bucket, but cant find an On-prem version. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no on-prem version of Amazon S3. However you can use another distributed file system that provide S3 compatible APIs like ceph. See the ceph s3 docs [here](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/).